# Plotting on a map

Tags: matlab, dictionary, plot

I'm plotting trajectories and right now, I just have figures with lines on it, corresponding to the list of LAT and LON that I brought in. How do I lay these trajectories over a map of the area that they're going over using the LAT and LON as limits on the map?

```
figure
for d = 1:i
hold on
plot(LON(d,:),LAT(d,:))
end
hold off
```

[image: A picture of one such trajectory plot.]

Comment: could you add some plot or more information?

Comment: @ironzionlion Sure thing. Should be attached to the problem now. (x-axis is longitude, y-axis is latitude)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Matlab Mapping Toolbox** is required for the following code.

```
LAT = [30, 40, 60];
LON = [-130, -90, -60]

coast_border = load('coast')  % Load coastline from Matlabs dataset
ax = worldmap('world')  % Create map figure
setm(ax, 'MapLatLimit', [min(LAT), max(LAT)], 'MAPLonLimit', [min(LON), max(LON)])
plotm(coast_border.lat, coast_border.long, 'k')  % Ploat coastline
plotm(LAT, LON, 'r')
```

[image: Output]

Note that you have to use **setm** instead of **set** if you want to change map settings.

Personally, i prefer to deactivate the Map-Grid and Labels and set the background color to blue

```
setm(ax,'meridianLabel','off','ParallelLabel','off','grid','off','ffacecolor',[0.6, 0.6, 1])
```

and fill the land

```
patchm(coast_border_lat, coast_border.long, [0.5 0.5 0.5])
```

Comment: This gets a map on there for me, but now, my trajectories don't want to stay on. I have 'hold on' set through the whole plotting process. Any thoughts?

Comment: are you using **plot** instead of **plotm**?  You should try *plotm(LAT, LON, 'r')*

Comment: Can you see the red line when you run the example from me?

Comment: A line between the first two points shows up. The third set of coordinates do not.

Comment: okay. i've the same issue with 3 points - when adding a fourth one everything is okay. So, in general it should work with your coordinates as well...